# Blue outline around active image

Tags: css, google-chrome

In Google Chrome, when I click on a linked image, the browser adds a blue outline around the image (please see the picture). How can I remove the outline? Tried this, no luck...

```
a img {
outline:none;
color:transparent;
}
```

[image: blue outline around image]

Comment: can you show an example.. here's a simple http://jsfiddle.net/zjV8N/, I don't see the issue.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qugahixe/1/edit the DEMO works for you?

Comment: The issue is 'selection' issue. I tried on my windows machine. Outline does not show. I tried on my ubuntu machine, it shows orange dotted outline on selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this method. check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qugahixe/1/edit)**.

```
a:focus{border: none; outline:none !important; }
```

Comment: Make sure to check on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You need another selector:

```
a:active
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
a:active{
    user-select: none;
   -o-user-select:none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Another option would be(probably the best one) not using img tag. Create a div instead and use CSS and use the image as that divs background-image.

Answer (score 1):

Make also outline none for a tag,

a { border:0px none; outline:0; }